# Pandas, Histogram Plotting With Subplots Based on Column Values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, histogram

I have a panda data table that looks something like this:

[image: Panda Table]

And it goes on through over a ton of rows. There's something like 30 or 40 different properties that I want to look at individually.

I'm looking to create a histogram for each individual property based on duration. So a histogram for property A, property B, property C, and so on....

I know how to do it for all properties, as seen in my below code:

```
df['duration'].plot(kind='hist', sharex=False, use_index=False, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the histogram of all properties]

Any ideas on how I might go about this?

Comment: I think its `df.groupby('property_name').hist()`

Comment: So I've done that, how do I get it to work if there is more than two columns. I did it just now and it is pulling a histogram for each column with numerical values. (so it's producing multiple histograms for each property). How can I create just one histogram for each property based on duration

Answer (score 2):

consider the following dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(duration=np.random.rand(1000),
                       property_name=np.random.choice(list('abc'), 1000)))
```

Then you can do

```
df.groupby('property_name').hist(figsize=(10,2))
```

[image]

Comment: So I've done that, how do I get it to work if there is more than two columns. I did it just now and it is pulling a histogram for each column with numerical values. (so it's producing multiple histograms for each property). How can I create just one histogram for each property based on duration – Josh Dautel just now   edit

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, got it!

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

```
df.groupby('property_name').hist(column='duration')
```